# Succubox crafting recipe list

Tags: succubox

Does anyone have a full crafting list for the game?

Basically I'm lazy and don't want to put in the effort of trying literally everything.

Comment: You can purchase the recipe lists in-game.

Comment: ....though the purchasable lists are severely limited, and often arrive long past when they'd come in handy.

Answer (score 18):

From the source code:

```
Ingredients: junk: 3
Produces: "1 metal",

Ingredients: metal: 2
Produces: "1 knife",

Ingredients: metal: 3
Produces: "1 gear",

Ingredients: knives: 1, common hats, 1
Produces: "1 fabric",

Ingredients: knives: 1, uncommon hats, 1
Produces: "2 fabric",

Ingredients: knives: 1, rare hats, 1
Produces: "1 fabric and 1 metal",

Ingredients: knives: 1, ultrarare hats, 1
Produces: "2 fabric and 1 gear",

Ingredients: knives: 1, legendary hats, 1
Produces: "10 fabric, 5 metal and 100 gold",

Ingredients: knives: 1, mythical hats, 1
Produces: "10 fabric and 1 magic",

Ingredients: knives: 1, cursed hats, 1
Produces: "1 cursed fabric and 1 free soul",

Ingredients: metal: 3, gears, 3, fabric, 3,
Produces: "1 robot without purpose",

Ingredients: robots: 1, knives, 1
Produces: "1 box cutting robot"

Ingredients: robots: 1, souls, 1
Produces: "a sentient robot! It has its own free will and just ran away.",

Ingredients: metal: 5, fabric, 1,
Produces: "a sword!",

Ingredients: swords: 1, magic, 1,
Produces: "a Magic Sword",

Ingredients: guns: 1, magic, 1,
Produces: "a Magic Gun",

Ingredients: swords: 1, souls, 1,
Produces: "a Soul Sword",

Ingredients: guns: 1, souls, 1,
Produces: "a Sentient Gun",

Ingredients: swords: 1, mysouls, 1,
Produces: "the Sword of Thyself",

Ingredients: guns: 1, mysouls, 1,
Produces: "the Gun of Thyself",

Ingredients: swords: 1, mysouls, 1, nothingness, 1, animosity, 1, guilt, 1, honesty, 1, freedom, 1, mojo, 1,
Produces: "the True Sword of Thyself",

Ingredients: guns: 1, mysouls, 1, nothingness, 1, animosity, 1, guilt, 1, honesty, 1, freedom, 1, mojo, 1,
Produces: "the True Gun of Thyself",

Ingredients: metal: 5, magic, 5, fabric, 25,
Produces: "a mass fabrication module!",

Ingredients: fabricators: 1, knives, 1,
Produces: "a knife",

Ingredients: fabricators: 1, swords, 1,
Produces: "a sword",

Ingredients: fabricators: 2,
Produces: "a... fabricator",

Ingredients: fabricators: 1, robots, 1, souls, 1,
Produces: "A Security Robot",

Ingredients: cursedfabric: 3, fabric, 2,
Produces: "The Book of Riddles",

Ingredients: magic: 15, metal, 15,
Produces: "a gun"

Ingredients: fabricators: 1, guns, 1,
Produces: "a gun",

Ingredients: fabricators: 1, common hats, 1,
Produces: "a hat , 2 mojo",

Ingredients: fabricators: 1, uncommon hats, 1,
Produces: "a hat, 20 mojo",

Ingredients: fabricators: 1, rare hats, 1,
Produces: "a hat , 200 mojo",

Ingredients: fabricators: 1, ultrarare hats, 1,
Produces: "a hat, 2K mojo",

Ingredients: fabricators: 1, legendary hats, 1,
Produces: "a hat, 20K mojo",

Ingredients: fabricators: 1, mythical hats, 1,
Produces: "a hat, 200K mojo",

Ingredients: fabricators: 1, cursed hats, 1,
Produces: "a hat , 2M mojo",

Ingredients: fabricators: 1, souls, 1,
Produces: "a soul",

Ingredients: nothingness: 1, souls, 1,
Produces: "a Dark Soul",
```

Comment: This answer lacks ... mojo.

Comment: Any hat with a fabricator will generate Mojo.