# I wasted my soul, how can I get a new one?

Tags: succubox

I got a shop item that offered me to reverse fabricate my soul, I did and got 1 'My own merged soul'. I tried to craft something with it, but got the message that I wasted my only soul :(.

I looked up the recipes at [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/320068/succubox-crafting-recipe-list) but it wasn't in the list. Is there an option to get another 'My own merged soul'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two options: just deal with it and do another run, or cheat.

If you want to just cheat it back, first open developer console (press F12), and run `data.mysouls.value = 1`. Also, if you get arrested for cheating, you can just run `data.jailtimer = 1` and get out of jail in a second.

Comment: Lost Soul + Mass Fabrication Device doesn't give you a "mysoul".

Comment: I guess I need to cheat :(

Comment: @schauk11erd thanks for the info, I removed that part from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Cheating doesn't seem to work. I tried to follow Ave's suggestion, but nothing changes, resulting in still having "My Own Merged Soul: 0".

Looks like you really only get one chance to use your own soul, so the only thing to do is reset.