# What is mojo used for

Tags: succubox

What is mojo used for in succubox is it important? since there is no crafting recipes I'm guessing it is not very important.

Answer (score 1):

Mojo is used for certain upgrades you can purchase.
Mojo is also used for a secret recipe to create a special weapon [listed in this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/320068/succubox-crafting-recipe-list).